# Auf oder in verschiedener Weise?

Tags: difference, usage, preposition

> Da ich Deutsch als dritte Sprache lerne, versuche ich, Wege und Mittel zu finden, um **auf verschiedener Weise** zu schreiben.
>
> Da ich Deutsch als dritte Sprache lerne, versuche ich, Wege und Mittel zu finden, um **in verschiedener Weise** zu schreiben.

Ich weiß nicht, was der Unterschied zwischen den zwei Ausdrücke ist. In meinem [Wörterbuch](http://www.dict.cc/?s=In+many+ways) steht, dass das **in verschiedener Weise** ist.

Comment: Ich finde keines von beiden passend.

Comment: Dein Satz hat sehr wenig Informationsgehalt. Was möchtest du denn genau aussagen? Geht es dir um einen großen Wortschatz? Oder darum, verschiedene Textformen zu schreiben (Berichte, Geschichten, ...)?

Comment: ...auf verschiedene Weise...?

Comment: @ Œlrim - Es geht darum,  nach Möglichkeiten zu suchen, wie man einen Satz bildet, ohne seine Bedeutung zu ändern.

Comment: Beide Versionen ergeben meines Erachtens keinen Sinn. Ich stimme @Œlrim zu: DerPolyglott33, was möchtest du denn ausdrücken?

Comment: Üblich wäre m.E. `Mittel und Wege` . Ich denke, was Du suchst, sind `unterschiedliche Formulierungen`.

Comment: Schlussendlich ist der ursprüngliche Satz ein schlechter Satz, um einen brauchbaren Satz daraus zu machen müsste man ihn völlig neu schreiben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der ursprüngliche Satz ist überkompliziert, und seine grammatikalischen Probleme können nur durch Vereinfachung des Satzes wirklich gelöst werden.
Wer längere Sätze bilden will, der darf seine Sätze nicht auf eine zu komplizierte Art aufbauen.

Das **Hervorheben gewisser Stellen** ist in diesem Fall hier sehr irreführend, da der ganze Satz ein wackeliges Konstrukt ist.

Ein anderes Problem ist, dass man die Redensart: "Art und Weise" durch "Art" ersetzen kann, aber nicht durch "Weise".
Der Reiz des Ausdrucks: "Art und Weise" besteht ja gerade darin, dass man das moderne Wort "Art" mit dem alten Wort "Weise" verbindet. Das ist ein Stilmittel.

Answer (score 0):

Dein Wörterbuch scheint bei „in many ways“ unvollständig zu sein: Zu „in various ways“ werden nämlich beide Varianten genannt. Wenn sowohl „auf“ als auch „in“ passen, sollte es nach meinem Gefühl keinen großen Unterschied geben.

Bei „auf diese Art/Weise“ denke ich persönlich eher an eine Methode (Handschrift, Schreibmaschine), bei „in dieser Art/Weise“ mehr an eine Eigenschaft (sachlich, poetisch).

Beispiel:
„Wir machen das **auf** meine Art!“ — „So etwas **in** dieser Art habe ich befürchtet.“